# RStudio addin reposition cursor

Tags: r, rstudio, add-in

I like to put a whitespace after parentheses because I find it increases readability of my code.
Like this:

```
some_function <- function( arg1, arg2, arg3 ) {
  # Doing things
}

some_list <- list( a1 = c( 1, 2, 3 ), a2 = "nothing" )
```

Since RStudio already auto-completes the parentheses I figured why not add the additional space as well to increase the laziness of my existence. I made an R package and followed the workflow described [here](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/).

Installed my package using `devtools::install_github("ErikSchutte/extrawhitespace")` 
and bound the addin to shift + 9. So everytime I would type `(` I would get `( ^ )` (`^` being the cursor location). What really bothers me though is that every first time I use the addin the cursor jumps to the start of the file..

The only thing I use so far is:

```
#' extrawhitespace
#'
#' Adds a whitespace after parentheses for readability.
#'
#' @importFrom rstudioapi insertText setCursorPosition
#' @export
extrawhitespace <- function() {
  context <- rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()
  start_line <- context$selection[[1]]$range$start[[1]]
  start_char <- context$selection[[1]]$range$start[[2]]
  insertText( "(  )" )
  setCursorPosition( c( start_line, start_char+2 ), id = NULL )
}
```

I can't find anything on this matter, can anyone give me push in the right direction?

Kind regards,

Erik